What does "the inferior is blessed by the superior" mean in Hebrews 7:7?
Hebrews 7:7 ESV

"It is beyond dispute that the inferior is blessed by the superior."

Here "blessed" is eulogertai.
Luke 2:28

"he took him up in his arms and blessed God and said,..".  blessed/eulogesen

Here Simeon blessed God. Simeon is surely inferior to God, so what does Heb 7:7  mean by "the inferior is blessed by the superior"?

Interesting that Simeon says 'Now thou lettest go thy bondman O Despot' (EGNT literal) yet he 'blessed the Deity'. I look forward to answers. Up-voted +1.

There are many, many cases in the OT where people are commanded to "bless the LORD", such as Gen 24:48, Deut 8:10, Judges 5:2, 9, 1 Chron 29:10, 20, 2 Chron 20:26, Neh 8:6, 9:5, Ps 26:12, 103:22, 104:35, 115:18, 134:1, 2, 135:19, 20, etc.
Equally, there are numerous cases where God blesses people such as: Deut 12:15, 16:10, 17, 1 Kings 8:66, Ps 129:8, Isa 19:25, etc.
Therefore, the act of blessing does NOT establish who is greater or lesser in the act of blessing.
The same is true in Heb 7:7 - which is merely the conclusion/summary to the list of evidence that Melchizedek was greater than Abraham.  Indeed, the author of Hebrews has an argument that proceeds as follows:
Melchizedek was truly great because:

he was king of Salem (V1)
He was priest of Most High God (V1)
He was able to bless even the great patriarch Abraham (V6)
He received tithes from Abraham V4)
His name means "King of Righteousness" and "King of Peace" (V2)
He had no genealogy, ie, "without beginning of days or end of life, like the Son of God, he remains a priest for all time." (V3)
He was a great priest without being descended from Levi; thus, even the priests of Levi, in a sense, gave tithes to Melchizedek (V9, 10).

Therefore, in view of all this, I see Heb 7:7 as a summary of all the arguments proffered by the author, that Melchizedek was even greater that Israel's most famous progenitor, Abraham.
Now, having established how great Melchizedek was, and his associated priesthood, the author of Hebrews says that Christ's priesthood was "in the order of Melchizedek" (V11, 17, Ps 110:4), ie, great and eternal.

In Hebrews 7:7 the context is Abraham receiving a blessing from the priest, Melchizedek, and then Abraham giving this superior one a tithe of all the spoils - Hebrews 7:1-4. One receives - the other gives.
Three times the word 'eulogeo' (meaning 'to speak well of') is used in those first seven verses of Hebrews chapter 7 according to Young's Exhaustive Concordance p. 98 middle column. That is the meaning of verse 7: Melchizedek spoke a blessing to Abraham, speaking well of Abraham. Then the argument is developed that Christ, our Great High Priest, is superior to the Levitical priesthood which could never deliver perfection, for Christ has done that by his one perfect sacrifice of himself. That is why Christ is such a blessing to his people.
That is why the word 'eulogia' (meaning 'good speech, or utterance') is used three times in Revelation this way; the first being uttered by many angels and the living creatures in heaven:

"Saying with a loud voice, Worthy is the Lamb that was slain to
receive power, and riches, and wisdom, and strength, and honour, and
glory, and blessing. And every creature which is in heaven, and on
the earth, and such as are in the sea, and all that are in them, heard
I saying, Blessing, and honour, and glory, and power, be unto him
that sitteth upon the throne, and unto the Lamb for ever and ever."
"Saying, Amen: Blessing, and glory, and wisdom, and thanksgiving,
and honour, and power and might, be unto our God for ever and ever.
Amen."  Revelation 5:12-13 & 7:12 A.V. [Emphasis mine]

That is the ultimate sense in which all creatures will bless God and the Lamb - every superlative possible can be spoken or sung unto God and his Christ - expressing spoken (or sung) heartfelt, supreme blessing on God. Worship in spirit and truth, indeed. We receive the blessing, then we give the due worship.
That helps us understand what Simeon did in the temple at Jerusalem when the eight-day-old Jesus was presented for circumcision, as per Luke 2:28. The word eulogeo (to speak well of) comes from Simeon as he holds the baby:

"Then took he him up in his arms, and blessed God, and said, Lord,
now lettest thou thy servant depart in peace, according to thy word:
for mine eyes have seen thy salvation... And Simeon blessed them
[Joseph and Mary], and said unto Mary his mother..." Luke 2:28-34 A.V.
[Emphasis mine]

This answer is that I understand a blessing to be both received and given in these ways:
(1) to speak well of another who is inferior to oneself, which is what Melchizedek did with regard to Abraham in the text in question.
(2) to speak well of another who is superior to oneself, which is what Simeon did with regard to the infant Jesus in the second text in question, and which we can do with regard to God and Christ, the spoken (or sung) blessing being worship.
(3) to do something for the blessing of an inferior, the superior one acting well for the inferior who cannot do what he receives, but to receive it - this is how God and Christ bless us.
It is astounding that those blessed by God and Christ can respond with worship which is deemed to be us blessing them, and which is accepted by them as such!
